# Рисование пальцами объекты и распознавание их

Tags: c#, unity3d

Здравствуйте, вообщем тут такое дело, понадобилось для игры создать что-то на подобии https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/#/content/1100 вот такую штуки, но я без понятия как такое сделать, может кто-то разбирается и может подсказать туториалы или какие-нибудь фичи что бы такое сделать. Мне прям не точь в точь, но хотя бы, если я нарисовал круг то мне выдало что это круг, а если я нарисовал квадрат мне выдало что это квадрат. Может кто-то подсказать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Вот здесь](http://www.tension-game.com/drawing_ru.php) есть флешка, которая делает именно то, что вы хотите. Можете декомпилировать её и попробовать разобраться, как она работает. Вкратце принцип такой: есть база данных со знаками. Знаки хранятся в виде набора координат точек знака в порядке их следования в знаке. Все координаты нормализованы (т. е. лежат в диапазоне от 0 до 1). Когда игрок зажимает мышку и начинает её двигать, начинается запись координат мышки в массив. Когда пользователь отпускает мышку, координаты нормализуются, и начинается поочерёдное сравнение с координатами каждого знака. В этой флешке сравниваются все координаты нарисованного игроком знака со всеми координатами знака из базы данных, для каждой точки, введённой игроком, ищется ближайшая точка из базы. Среднее расстояние до ближайших точек запоминается для каждого знака из базы. После проверки всех знаков из базы, ищется тот, для которого среднее расстояние наименьшее. Этот знак считается совпавшим. Если все средние расстояния больше некоторого порога срабатывания, то считается, что ни один знак не подошёл. Вариант плох тем, что его сложность O(N*M*K), где N - число знаков в базе (для большей точности распознавания нужно по нескольку образцов каждого знака), M - число точек в знаке, введённом игроком, K - среднее число точек в знаках из базы.

Есть ещё один вариант, менее ресурсоёмкий, но боле сложный в реализации. Почитайте про нейронные сети, они часто используются для распознавания образов. Но вам придётся её долго обучать, и как-то решать вопрос, в каком виде представлять входнве данные (ибо входов у нейронной сети фиксированное количество, а число точек в фигуре, нарисованной пользователем, может сильно варьироваться).

Comment: Что-то мне кажется в примере который я привел нету таких сложных функций, но спасибо за совет.